# How to return custom 403 exception when using Laravel 5.1 authorize method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, acl, laravel-authorization

In laravel 5.1 you can return a custom response when you check abilities if you use the following method:

```
if (Gate::denies('update', $post)) {
        return response()->view('errors.403');
}
```

Is there any way to return a similar custom error when using the authorize method:

```
$this->authorize('update', $post);
```

The above simply throws a http exception with status code 403.

Comment: How about using `abort('403')` inside authorize method

Comment: How would you pass that through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can do it in following way:

In `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` add the following method:

```
protected function createGateUnauthorizedException(
    $ability,
    $arguments,
    $message = 'This action is unauthorized.',
    $previousException = null
) {
    throw $previousException;
}
```

It will rethrow `UnauthorizedException`.

Now in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` you can add at the beginning of `render` method:

```
if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\Access\UnauthorizedException)  {
    return response()->view('errors.403');
}
```