# How to redirect another page instead of redirecting to abort 403 error page in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

My question is whenever there is a 403 error I should redirect to my own custom page or show the flash message(on the same page) something like that.How can I achieve this in Laravel?.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **app/Exceptions/Handler.php** for this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e->getStatusCode() == 403) {
        return redirect('yourpage'); // this will be on a 403 exception
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e); // all the other exceptions
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thomas that did not work, it is redirecting to default error page not where I want to redirect, Thank you

Comment: Well this should work, can you check the status code is indeed 403?

Comment: I think I choose the wrong function, it should be `getStatusCode` not `getCode`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451012/how-to-return-custom-view-for-http-error-response-in-laravel-5

Comment: This doesn't work reliably. `$e->getStatusCode()` often throws an exception `Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError::getStatusCode()` - for example on a `TokenMismatchException`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view for specific HTTP error codes. If you set up a Blade template at `resources/views/errors/403.blade.php`, it will get used for all 403 error responses.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages)

Alternatively you can set up a custom exception handler for 403 responses if you need something more involved. I found a good example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34256000/how-to-return-custom-403-exception-when-using-laravel-5-1-authorize-method).

Answer (score 0):

```
you can make you own page in inside the view .resources/views/errors/yourblade.blade.php
```

after that just return your page to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app/Exceptions/Handler.php for this as Thomas Moors stated above or you can use a try catch for basic error handling.

```
try {
 do Something //
}
catch (Exception $e) {
//log error in log file or dv
return redirect->('home');
}
```